# Create a symbolic link in the current directory

Tags: command-line, symlink

I have got a question were I have to create a symbolic link named "new" to file /test/test1/test2. The current command I have is this:

```
ln -s /test/test1/test2 /new
```

I am not if there is a specific command which will create it in the current directory?

Comment: Can you try to explain your question more clearly?  For example, have you *tried* the command you have now?  What happens?  Why do you think you need more help?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

-With this you are just trying create a symbolic link at 'root' /  -  '/new', with the name "new" and this you can't do it like a simple user... "the rigths of write of folder 'root - /' not permite this!"...

the command:

> ln -s /test/test1/test2  new

Just goes permite you create a symbolic link at the folder you are since you have permissions, to create files and folders in that folder!

Comment: yes. alternately, use `./new` (with a dot) to place the new link in the current directory.